# Insert subcategories inside Shopware6 custom block

Tags: shopware6

I have created a custom block that i use inside "listing page" using this guide https://developer.shopware.com/docs/v/6.4/guides/plugins/plugins/content/cms/add-cms-block.

I want to display in this block a list all subcategories of the current category.
so a created a text block and i am trying to populate it with subcategories looking for the right variable to pick using {{dump()}}.

The problem is that i don't know how to pick the current category variable and his children, looking in documentation i can't find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `navigation` property using the `header` accessor of the `page` to find the currently active category and get its children.

```
{% set currentCategoryId = page.header.navigation.active.id %}
{% set currentCategoryChildren = page.header.navigation.getChildren(currentCategoryId).tree %}
{{ dump(currentCategoryChildren) }}
```

Comment: it works! thank you. If i would like to add also the number of products per category ?
i tried to look in: treeItem.products but #products is null even if i have some products for that category.

Comment: Please create a new question for this